# JavaScript - Wait until DOM modification within AJAX callback has been completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, web

So, I have the following code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Retrieve menu html
    $.get('/modules/menu.php', function(data) {
        //Load menu html
        $('main#main').prepend(data);
    });

    //Initialize Menu
    menuInit();

    $('#menuToggle').click(function() {
        $('#main_menu').fadeToggle();
    });
});
```

`menuInit()` successfully modifies DOM elements when included in the html directly instead of using `$.get()`,so the intialization has no issues, however, when using ajax, the intialization of the menu starts before the DOM elements are fully loaded.

I've made a little research and `.prepend()` does not support callbacks, so not an option.

Surrounding `menuInit()` with a `setTimeOut()` with 100 ms works, but it will most certainly fail with slow connections, I need something more dynamic.

Comment: What happens if you move the `menuInit()` call into the `$.get()` success callback after `.prepend()`? (You don't need a `.prepend()` callback.)

Comment: Hahahaha, awesome! You just fixed it o.O I thought I had tried that...

Answer (score 0):

Just put the rest of the code inside the callback so it executes after the data has been added to the page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Retrieve menu html
    $.get('/modules/menu.php', function(data) {
        //Load menu html
        $('main#main').prepend(data);

        //Initialize Menu
        menuInit();

        $('#menuToggle').click(function() {
            $('#main_menu').fadeToggle();
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: @TheCamps10 - Did this answer your question?